# How to use Bottom tabActivity in my Activity itself

Tags: java, android, tabs

I want to use bottom tab in my activity,in my old activity itself having some function,without using seperate activity for tab,can i use tab functions in my activity itself,I tried like this.

```
public class GinfyActivity extends Activity {


    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

    public GridviewAdapter mAdapter;
    private Spinner spinner1;
    public String selectprayer;


    ArrayList<GridviewAdapter> results = new ArrayList<GridviewAdapter>();

    private ArrayList<String> listginfy;
    private ArrayList<Integer> listimage;

    private GridView gridView;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home_ginfy);

        TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);

        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test1").setIndicator("TAB 1").setContent(new Intent(GinfyActivity.this,Audioprayer.class)));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(new Intent(GinfyActivity.this,TTSMeditation.class)));
        mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test3").setIndicator("TAB 3").setContent(new Intent(GinfyActivity.this,TTSList.class)));

        mTabHost.setCurrentTab(0);

        addListenerOnButton();
        addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection();






        prepareList();


        // prepared arraylist and passed it to the Adapter class
   mAdapter = new GridviewAdapter(this,listginfy, listimage);

        // Set custom adapter to gridview
        gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
        gridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        // Implement On Item click listener
        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() 
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position, long id) {


                if (selectprayer.equals("www.ginfy.com"))
                {

                switch(position)
                { 
                case 0:
                Intent newActivity = new Intent(GinfyActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                startActivity(newActivity);
                break;

                case 2:
                Intent new1Activity = new Intent(GinfyActivity.this,AndroidTabLayoutActivity.class);
                startActivity(new1Activity);
                break;
                default:
                    Toast.makeText(GinfyActivity.this, "Coming Soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
                else
                {

                    switch(position)
                    {
                    case 0:
                    Intent new2Activity = new Intent(GinfyActivity.this,YourPrayerActivity.class);
                    startActivity(new2Activity);
                    break;

                    case 1:
                    Intent new3Activity = new Intent(GinfyActivity.this,AndroidTabLayoutActivity1.class);
                    startActivity(new3Activity);
                    break;

                    case 3:
                    Intent new4Activity = new Intent(GinfyActivity.this,ExperiencesActivity.class);
                    startActivity(new4Activity);
                    break;
                    default:
                        Toast.makeText(GinfyActivity.this, "Coming Soon", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }


                }
            }
        });
    }




    public void addListenerOnSpinnerItemSelection() {
        {
            spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
            spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() 
            {
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                        long id) {

                    spinner1.setSelection(position);
                    //spinnerCapital.setSelection(position);

                    selectprayer = (String) spinner1.getSelectedItem();

                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), selectprayer, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    //String myStatesCapital = (String) spinnerCapital.getSelectedItem();



                    //tvCapital.setText("My State is " + myState + ".And its Capital is "
                            //+ myStatesCapital);

                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }});
        }
        }




    public void addListenerOnButton() {
        spinner1 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);

    }

    public void prepareList()
    {
        listginfy = new ArrayList<String>();

        listginfy.add("Prayers");
        listginfy.add("Prayer room");
        listginfy.add("God gallery");
        listginfy.add("Experiences");


        listimage = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        listimage.add(R.drawable.ginfyprayer);
        listimage.add(R.drawable.poojaroom1);
        listimage.add(R.drawable.godsgallery);
        listimage.add(R.drawable.temp1);

    }


}
```

I declared that tab functions in mylayout also but my activity is not opening,it display my activity has stopped

is showing somelogcat error.

```
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.jsonandroid/com.example.jsonandroid.GinfyActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5039)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at com.example.jsonandroid.GinfyActivity.onCreate(GinfyActivity.java:44)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
09-12 08:43:45.615: E/AndroidRuntime(2630):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: Not sure what you tried to achieve...  but I guess this error isn't related to it : you've got an NPE on line 44, check this line. ( for example, is gridView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridView1); actually found the gridView1 id ?  Would be help full to see which line is the line 44 ^^

Comment: @Guian i want to show only the tabs,because both activities are mingle,i want to show only the tab alone dude

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your your complete requirement **https://github.com/AdilSoomro/Iphone-Tab-in-Android**

Answer (score 2):

replace these two lines

```
public class GinfyActivity extends Activity
TabHost mTabHost = (TabHost)findViewById(android.R.id.tabhost);
```

with following

```
public class GinfyActivity extends TabActivity
TabHost mTabHost = getTabHost();
```

**EDIT**

change activity which you want to display in following line.

```
Intent intentAndroid = new Intent().setClass(this, Your_Activity.class);
```

And if you want only `Tab` then it's better to use `ActionBar` as TabHost is deprecated.

[Full Example](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-tablayout-example/) of TabHost

To use `ActionBar` here is sample code (use Sherlock or appcompat Library for < API 11)

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements TabListener {
ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    actionBar=getActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB 1").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB 2").setTabListener(this));
    actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab().setText("TAB 3").setTabListener(this));
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    switch (tab.getPosition()) {
    case 0:
        //start activity here or toast
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start First Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case 1:
        //start activity here or toast
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Second Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;
    case 2:
        //start activity here or toast
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Start Third Activity", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }

}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

 }
```

Comment: its asking have to create method of getTabHost();

Comment: have you replace `Activity` with `TabActivity` ?

Comment: ya dude,its working fine,but i dont want to display those activity i want to show only the tabs alone not that activity because its overlapping that actvity

Comment: i dont want to show that activity,i want to show only the tabs alone because its overlapping eachother,while clicking the tab alone it has to go to that activity

Comment: please refer link provided in my answer.

Comment: ya dude i saw that link,but i want that tabs alone want to show not that activity because behind one more activity is there

Comment: for me i dont want to show that activity in that page itself,i want to show the tab only not the activity,while clicking the tab,it has to go to that activity ,how to do that one dude,    mTabHost.addTab(mTabHost.newTabSpec("tab_test2").setIndicator("TAB 2").setContent(new Intent(GinfyActivity.this,TTSMeditation.class)));

Comment: download example from above link and run you will get idea.

Comment: dude what is my need is i want to show the tabs in bottom,but it has to show the old activity of that page only while clicking the tab only it has to go to that activity.rite now its overlapping old and new tab1activity.Where i have to use "Action Bar"

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/37244/discussion-between-ketan-and-karthick-m)